# XCODE Beta Development

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7-beta3

I have a question about the BETA realeases of XCODE. Now it is possible to download the BETA of XCODE7. 
Is it possible to Develop a complete Application from this BETA, with installer etc. or will I have to wait for a standart Version?

The reason behind this question is that I would like to use the try/catch in Swift 2.0 so I would not need a bridging header and objective C.

Comment: You can develop anything you want. You can't submit anything ever to Apple with any Beta software. Even once ios9 is out you can't submit with the beta version.

Comment: You will still be using Objective-C since that is what Cocoa Touch is mostly written in. Also what does using try/catch in Swift 2.0 so have to do with a bridging header and/or objective-C?

Comment: I have written a tray application where i did not have to use objective-c code. It is completely in swift. The try catch is missing for some functions so I made a bridging header to use the try catch in objective-c.

Comment: Thank you @Fogmeister If you post your comment as an answer i will mark it as correct. Thats all i wanted to know.

Comment: @Silve2611 In Objective-C exceptions are to be used only for non-recoverable programming errors, not to control program execution. Specifically throwing exceptions across stack frames is not cleanly handled. The try/catch in Swift 2.0 are is not really exception handling, it just borrows some of the naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fogmeister gave the right answer: "You can develop anything you want. You can't submit anything ever to Apple with any Beta software. Even once ios9 is out you can't submit with the beta version"